# Switching from JWPlayer to Flowplayer

Tags: javascript, html, video, jwplayer, flowplayer

I am trying to build a web interface for Subsonic and was trying to switch its default implementation of JWPlayer to Flowplayer.

I tried the default method of loading the video in both JWPlayer and Flowplayer and neither works, so I looked at the existing interface which used the below relevant code:

```
var player;
var position;
var maxBitRate = 1000;
var timeOffset = 0;

function init() {
    var flashvars = {
        id:"player1",
        skin:"flash/whotube.zip",
        screencolor:"000000",
        controlbar:"over",
        autostart:"false",
        bufferlength:3,
        backcolor:"EFEFEF",
        frontcolor:"000000",
        provider:"video"
    };
    var params = {
        allowfullscreen:"true",
        allowscriptaccess:"always"
    };
    var attributes = {
        id:"player1",
        name:"player1"
    };

    var width = "100%";
    var height = "85%";
    swfobject.embedSWF("flash/jw-player-5.6.swf", "placeholder1", width, height, "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
}

function playerReady(thePlayer) {
    player = $("player1");
    player.addModelListener("TIME", "timeListener");
    play();    
}

function play() {
    var list = new Array();
    list[0] = {
        file:"http://domain.com:4040/rest/stream.view?u=username&p=password&v=1.6.0&c=appname&id=number",
        duration:9999 - timeOffset, //testing value for duration
        provider:"video"
    };
    player.sendEvent("LOAD", list);
    player.sendEvent("PLAY");
}
```

I can't even same to make anything run under flowplayer. Any ideas? I am stuck at:

1. Getting something equivalent to playerReady();
2. Getting the video to load using:

   flowplayer.addClip({'url':videoURL},0);
   flowplayer.play({'url':videoURL},0);

Which gives me: has no method 'addClip' and has no method 'play'

My JS include are for both FlowPlayer and JWPlayer:
flowplayer-3.2.11.min.js
Jquery
Prototype
swfobject
and my own JS file from which above is a snippet.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.15.swf", {
            clip: {
                scaling: 'orig'
            },
            plugins: {
                controls: null
            },
            // player events are defined directly to "root" (not inside a clip)
            onLoad: function() {
                $f().play({url: "http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/Extremists.flv"});
            }
        });
```